# Pardot + Sales Cloud: implementing event marketing

Tags: pardot

We are currently unsure if we are using Sales Cloud + Pardot like it is intended. Therefore I am asking for help because our current process of event invitations is very odd.

Our current process looks like this:

- Create a new Field for the event in the Salescloud. Lets call this event "Dreamforce".
- The field is a checkbox (because you can inline edit this faster inside a listview)
- Give the account managers and marketing departments time to check this value in a list view with inline editing inside the Salescloud
- Take this Salescloud list and import it to Pardot using the manual import process
- Send an email via Pardot to this list

This creates a ton of new fields if you are planning to send email invitations to customers in various countries for various events. Creating a field with multiselect is not wanted because it is not easy to edit inline using a listview.

How can we make this process smarter?

Comment: Step 1: if not done, implement automated [prospect sync](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce-pardot-integration) between Pardot and Sales Cloud. Step 2: automate the addition and/or removal of prospects to/from list(s) via automation rules: [Classic](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/pardot-process-automation/use-automation-rules) / [Lightning](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/pardot-process-automation-lightning). You can also send email via rules. When done, you'll have a much more efficient process.

Comment: I am searching for the way to synchronize Lists / Campaigns from Salesforce to Pardot. The other way arround I can use actions like Add to CRM campaign, but i do not get how i can send a salesforce list to pardot (or campaign members to pardot).

Comment: Campaigns: take a look at https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/234/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/pardot_connected_campaigns_implementation_guide.pdf . This is an advanced subject, you need to understand and implement Pardot basics first. Start here: https://pages.mail.salesforce.com/gettingstarted/pardot/